# Jenkins fetch tag from two repository

Tags: git, jenkins

I just want to fetch Tag from two different git repository in the same Job.
Is it possible to do that without plugin ?

Comment: yes clone two repos and cd to each repo path and fetch tag of the repo

Comment: Ok because i want to have a job with two parameter, the tag list from two repositories.

Comment: So i need to use git parameter plugins, it is not possible to do that by configuring git parameter ?

Comment: you can fetch them using the refspec in job configuration, use that parameter there. Each parameter is is an environment variable and jenkins git plugin allows using environment variables to specify what refspec/branch/tag to get, so you can for sure use that input parameter.

Comment: When i try to use refspec i have this :  !No Git repository configured in SCM configuration

Comment: Jenkins repositories allow you to add multiple repository, but how i make the correspondence between repositories and git tag build parameter

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Extensible Choice Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Extensible+Choice+Parameter+plugin) with a custom Groovy script to fetch your tags.

In your build configuration, add an `Extensible Choice` parameter, choose `System Groovy Choice Parameter` as the **Choice Provider** and insert the following script:

```
def tags = []
"git ls-remote -t <YOUR-REPO-URL-HERE>".execute().text.eachLine {
    tags.add(it.split()[1].replaceAll('\\^\\{\\}', '').replaceAll('refs/tags/', ''))
}
tags = tags.unique().reverse()
return tags
```

The script will dynamically fill in a select box for your choice parameter with the tag names.
You can add as many of these parameters as you fancy.

Comment: But with this script i need to pass credentials to connect to my repositories, it is not automatic ?

Comment: It will use your default git user, if you have it set up. Otherwise you can try using `<git_user>:<psswd>@<your_git_repo>`.

Comment: Hum ok, but it is not possible to manage this with the Jenkins git credential id ?

Comment: You can take a look a some thing like [Credentials Binding Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Binding+Plugin), or try to set up a global password in Jenkins system management. That's about all I can think of right now :). Hope this helps a little.

Answer (score 0):

This  problem is solved by using ssh connection.

I put my public key on my gitlab and i use the ssh url to make the connection on my groovy script.